# Spark: How to write files to s3/hdfs from each executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use case where I am running some modeling code on each executor and want to store the result in s3/hdfs immediately before waiting for all the executors to finish the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe write API works in the same fashion you intend to use here, if you write the dataframe into hdfs, the executors will independently write the data into files rather bringing them all to the driver and then performing the write operation.

Refer this [link](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-DataFrameWriter.html) to further read  this topic.